# Timing of document.write injected javascripts

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-analytics, timing

It looks like this code is causing a timing problem. At what point after the execution of this script will ga.js run? How can we be sure that ga.js has executed if it's injected in this manner? (Another component depends on it)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
```

Comment: It should be loaded and executed synchronously, being usable directly after the `write` command. What timing problem do you have?

Comment: ReferenceError: _gat is not defined

Comment: But only under certain circumstances. Mitigated by moving script block to top of page instead of bottom.

Comment: That's what I thought, the `document.write` will be executed synchronously, the loading of the script tag however is on another timeframe since it's injected right into the middle of all http requests. You don't know unless you capture it's load event. Hence GA suggests to put this script in the head tag.

Comment: And where do you use `_gat`?

Comment: @Tim yes that's what I thought too. Seems like a race condition. Does putting it in the head really solve this?

Comment: This will block rendering (at least used to in older browsers, not sure how modern browsers handle this) until the script is loaded. This makes sure the ga functions are available (so put it at the page top and you're safe), but in the olden (pre-broadband) days caused white screens when the script could not be loaded (which is one of the reasons Google moved to asychnronous script injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't strictly answer your question about document.write but it should solve your problem.

ga.js is designed to be used asynchronously. You should be able to do something like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(function(){
    // Use _gat here freely
});
```

The function pushed into _gaq will be processed once ga.js is loaded.

Also it seems like you are using a fairly old version of this code. The newer version doesn't use document.write.

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

If you decide to update your analytics tracking code, I'd recommend you jumping straight to Universal Analytics, that uses a different file called analytics.js instead.